# Export indexeddb object store to .csv

Tags: java, csv, export, indexeddb

I have an object store I need to export or download as a .csv file. I have done some searching and I can't seem to find information on this function. Responses that do not utilize IDB are welcome.

**Some background:** This is part of a project for work, and I dove into this project without prior knowledge of coding whatsoever. I am using a company issued chromebook, so (as far as I know) NPM installs are not available.

**App Background:** The project is a customer survey operated through a single terminal. That terminal being my chromebook with hopes to move to an ipad if I can successfully download user inputs to .csv file.

What I have so far:

```
  (function leadIDB() {

window.indexedDB = window.indexedDB || window.mozIndexedDB || window.webkitIndexedDB|| window.msIndexedDB;

if (!window.indexedDB) {
  alert('indexDB not supported in this browser');
}

let request = window.indexedDB.open("leadDB", 1),
  db,
  tx,
  store,
  index;

request.onupgradeneeded = function(e) {
  let db = request.result,
    store = db.createObjectStore("LeadStore", {keyPath: "leadID", autoIncrement: true});
      index = store.createIndex("firstName", "firstName", {unique: false});
};

request.onerror = function(e) {
  console.log("There was an error: " + e.target.errorCode);
};

request.onsuccess = function(e) {
  db = request.result;
  tx = db.transaction("LeadStore", "readwrite");
  store = tx.objectStore("LeadStore");
  index = store.index("firstName");

  db.onerror = function(e) {
    console.log("ERROR" + e.target.errorCode);
  };

  store.put(newLead);


  let lead = store.getAll();

  lead.onsuccess = function() {
    console.log(lead.result);
    console.log(lead.result.firstName);
  };


  tx.oncomplete = function() {
    console.log('Item added to LeadDB');
    db.close();
  };
 };
})();
```

Comment: There is no function that does this for you, you will need to write a small script. Do you have any code where you have attempted to do this yourself.

Comment: I don't really know where to begin as far as retrieving the object store and downloading as CSV. I appended my question above to include the code that creates and adds items to the object store.

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right track. There are a few more things to do. First, you need to be able to continue processing once you have loaded the data from indexedDB into js memory. Next, you need to generate the CSV file in memory (as a gigantic string). Next, you need to convert the csv string into a [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) (which implements [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob)). Finally, you want to trigger the download of the file.

There are a few ways to do the first step. I am going to use a promise, but you could do this with a callback or whatever you fancy.

```
function loadData() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var openrequest = indexedDB.open(...);
    openrequest.onupgradeneeded = ...;
    openrequest.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
    openrequest.onsuccess = event => {
      var db = event.target.result;
      var txn = db.transaction(...);
      var store = txn.objectStore(...);
      var loadrequest = store.getAll();
      loadrequest.onerror = event => reject(event.target.error);
      loadrequest.onsuccess = event => {
        var data = event.target.result;
        resolve(data);
      };
    };
  });
}

// You could call the function like this for example:
async function foo() {
  var data = await loadData();
  console.log('loaded the data, loaded %d objects', data.length);
}
```

Next, you want to convert the data into a csv-formatted string.

```
// This is not perfect, just an example of getting you closer
function toCSV(data) {
  var output = [];
  for(var object of data) {
    var row = [];
    for(var prop in object) {
      row.push(to_csv_value(object[prop]));
      row.push(',');
    }
    row.push('\n');
    output.push(row.join(''));
  }

  return output.join('');
}

function to_csv_value(value) {
  var output = '"';
  output += value.replace('"', '\\"');
  return output + '"';
}

// and then to compose it for example:
async function foo() {
  var data = await loadData();
  var csvstring = toCSV(data);
}
```

Next, you want to create a file. You can use the Blob constructor to do this. Something like the following:

```
// Because File implements blob interface, we are effectively creating a file
// by creating a blob
function createCSVFileFromString(string) {
  var csv_mime_type = 'text/csv';
  return new Blob([string], {type: csv_mime_type});
}

// And again, to compose it:
async function foo() {
  var data = await loadData();
  var string = toCSV(data);
  var blob = createCSVFileFromString(string);
}
```

The next step is to make the blob downloadable. This can typically be done using the object url strategy. Kind of like the following:

```
function downloadBlob(blob, filename) {
  var anchor = document.createElement('a');
  anchor.setAttribute('download', filename);
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  anchor.setAttribute('href', url);
  anchor.click();
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

// And finally, to compose it all together
async function loadAndStartDownloadingData() {
  var data = await loadData();
  var csvstring = toCSV(data);
  var blob = createCSVFileFromString(csvstring);
  downloadBlob(blob, 'mydata.csv');
}
```

Then, somewhere in your application, let's say on click of button, you would do something like this. Im using non-async syntax here just for example of using promise in non-await, you want to always be careful to not hide errors.

```
var button = ...;
button.onclick = function(event) {
  // Load the data and trigger the download, and send any problems to console
  loadAndStartDownloadingData().catch(console.warn);
};
```

Note, this doesn't cover inserting the data, but I'm sure you can figure that out.

Comment: Thank you! Since the IDB logs HTML form inputs, does that cover inserting the data?

If I could ask, could you further clarify the steps needed? I have the object store created and user inputs are currently being logged into the DB. 

Correct me if I'm wrong, before I close the DB I need to:
-Retrieve the data using the getAll() method
-Convert those objects to strings (not entirely sure how to do that for IDB)
-Construct a blob from that string (there is plenty of literature on that subject)
-Make the blob downloadable
-Tie that download function to a trigger (I'll be using a button)